# Propagate yield from generators while using them in the same way (reuse)

Tags: javascript, generator, yield, reusability

I have an iterator that I want to break into functions, for example, the full iterator:

```
export function* myIterator(foo) {
 for (const xs of foo) {
   for (const ys of xs.y) {
    for (const zs of ys.z) {
      if (zs) {
        for (const qs of zs.q) {
          if (qs) {
            yield qs;
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

To:

```
export function* myIterator(xs) {
   for (const ys of xs.y) {
    for (const zs of ys.z) {
      if (zs) {
        for (const qs of zs.q) {
          if (qs) {
            yield qs;
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
}

function* myOuterIterator(foo) {
  for (const xs of foo) {
    yield myIterator(xs);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't keep the same behavior in a `for of`. Is there a way to reuse generators?

(removing the yield from `myOuterIterator` doesn't help either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yield*` to yield the results of `myIterator`:

```js
function* myIterator(xs) {
    for (const ys of xs.y) {
     for (const zs of ys.z) {
       if (zs) {
         for (const qs of zs.q) {
           if (qs) {
             yield qs;
           }
         }
       }
     }
    }
 }

 function* myOuterIterator(foo) {
    for (const xs of foo) {
      yield *myIterator(xs);
    }
  }

let f = [
    {y: [{z: [{q:[10]}]}, {z: [{q:[20]}]}, {z: [{q:[30]}]}]},
    {y: [{z: [{q:[100]}]}, {z: [{q:[200]}]}, {z: [{q:[300]}]}]}
]

let gen = myOuterIterator(f)
console.log([...gen])
```

Comment: Nice. Does python have something like this too?

Comment: @shinzou, I'm not sure about python.